# How to make a separate android app that merges with parent app ? Like theme apps for launchers

Tags: android, apk, android-launcher

Like many launchers have separate android theme apps.
i wish to have same, a separate app that add images to parent app.

I have a android app [Brightness Dimmer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dbs.brightnessdimmer). Now i am interested to makes many Images Pack for **Toucher** ( OnScreen Controller ).

What is best approach to get it implemented?
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Android applications may share data between each other. About sharing data you can read [here](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html), its worth pointing that there is such [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getResourcesForApplication%28java.lang.String%29) that allows for sharing resources between applications(resources are images, strings, etc..)
If you want to create proper extensions for other applications here is great open source [example](https://github.com/romannurik/dashclock) written by Roman Nurik